# Asymptotic behaviour of the integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, asymptotics

Suppose I have the integral
$$
\tag 1 I\left[p\equiv -\frac{1}{2}\pm ia, z\right] \equiv \frac{1}{\Gamma(-p)}\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xz -\frac{x^{2}}{2}}x^{-p-1}dx
$$
I'm interested in asymptotic behaviour of this integral for the case $a\to \infty$, $a \to 0$. I know that for limit $|z| \to \infty$, $|z| >>|p|$ the asymptotic behaviour of $(1)$ is
$$
I\sim e^{-\pi a}
$$
Could someone clarify to me how to extract behaviour of $(1)$ for $a\to \infty$, $z$ is arbitrary?

Comment: Make the change of variables $u=zx$ and you will be able to evaluate the integral in terms of gamma function and things will be clear.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal : aorry, I made the mistake when writing the integral.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal : I've corrected the integral.

Comment: If useful, your integral can be written in terms of Kummer function $$I\left[p\equiv -\frac{1}{2}\pm ia, z\right] \equiv \frac{1}{\Gamma(-p)}\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xz -\frac{x^{2}}{2}}x^{-p-1}dx=\sqrt{\pi }\, 2^{-\frac{1}{4}\pm\frac{i a}{2}} \left(\frac{\, _1F_1\left(\frac{1}{4}\mp\frac{i a}{2};\frac{1}{2};\frac{z^2}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\mp\frac{i a}{2}\right)}-\frac{\sqrt{2} z \, _1F_1\left(\frac{3}{4}\mp\frac{i a}{2};\frac{3}{2};\frac{z^2}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\mp\frac{i a}{2}\right)}\right)$$

Comment: @ppooppii : yes, it is in fact parabolic cylinder function in integral representation.

Comment: What does $a \to \infty, a \to 0$ mean?